# Back to left button using CSS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two questions:

1. There are lots of examples on how to animate a `back to top` button using CSS or JQuery.  Is there any example to do the same for `back to left` button (when I am scrolling horizontally).
2. How to link a button `A` to button `B`  on the same page and play them in a loop? 
   I mean, if I click `A` it should go to the position of button`B`. And when I click `B` it should return to the position of button `A'

Any suggestions.

Comment: Your question is too broad. For answer 1. you may want to check out jQuery `scrollTop()` vs `scrollLeft()`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/

Answer (score 1):

To link those two buttons the code might look like this:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<button id="one"><a href="#two"> ONE </a> </button>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<button id="two"> <a href="#one"> TWO </a> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: the method `window.scrollTo()` accepts two arguments, the vertical position (in pixels) of where you want to scroll to, and the horizontal position. So you should be able to do something like the following to scroll you all the way back left while maintaining your current vertical scroll.

```
window.scrollTo($(window).scrollTop(), 0);
```

As for the second question, you can give both buttons a unique ID, like:

```
<a id="btnA" href="#btnB" class="button">A</a>

<a id="btnB" href="#btnA" class="button">B</a>
```